# How to block Magento from Auto-sending CreditMemo after PayPal refund?

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, creditmemo, ipn

Basically, when I send refund via paypal to a customer, Magento automatically sends Credit Meme to the customer. Often time, the information is incorrect in the credit memo.

How to block Magento from automatically sending Credit Memo email after PayPal refund?

**Does turning off IPN in PayPal settings will eliminate the automatic Credit Memo creation in Magento ?**

Comment: you need to modify magento core functinoality to stop this sending.

Comment: I get that, but the question what exactly to edit in the core?

Comment: tell me what you are not know into that code?

Comment: I dont know where to make changes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off IPN in Paypal settings will shut off all handling of postback data from Paypal.

To stop the automatic creation of creditmemos, make a local copy (or overload) app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php and change the function _registerTransaction() by commenting out the line (approx 379)

```
$this->_registerPaymentRefund();
```

If you want the creditmemo to be created but just no email being sent out, change the same file in function _registerPaymentRefund() by commenting out line (approx 580)

```
$creditmemo->sendEmail();
```